# array returns different result that I expected in php

Tags: php, arrays

i wrote php code like this.

```
if(...) {
   $array[] = 1;
}
else if(...) {
   $array[] = 2;
}
else {
   $array[] = 3;
}
```

I didn't declare $array variable before It used.

But when I check value in this variable , It returns [1,2,3]

I think It is local variable so I expected [3] but I dont't know why result is [1,2,3]

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I would suspect your if statements are in a loop and it is catching all of your if conditions. Please provide more of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $array[] = $var;

is just equivalent to the native function **array_push**.

See [docu](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

So basically, you are pushing elements to your Array $array.